# No more project showcases?

Tags: discussion

I saw that there was a [Project Showcase '14](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/876/project-showcase-14) but I could not find other project showcases. I also could not find [reasons why it should not be repeated every year](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=project+showcase).

I really liked the projects from that showcase. Any chance that such an event is repeated?